# Issue using Inner/Outer Joins in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's is my main table. where i have three column with there dates. some of them are NULL values. i want to have outputt some thing like given below. i tried alot but couldnt get the correct answer. if someone can help. thanks.

```
a.id  a.date       b.id   b.date      c.id   c.date
3     7/1/2014     11     NULL        21     NULL
5     8/1/2014     12     NULL        22     NULL
5     8/1/2014     13     NULL        22     NULL
5     8/1/2014     12     NULL        23     NULL
5     8/1/2014     13     NULL        23     NULL
6     NULL         14     06/01/2014  24     NULL
7     NULL         15     NULL        25     09/01/2014
```

Desired Output

```
a.id  b.id   c.id   date
3     11     21     07/01/2014
5     12     22     08/01/2014
5     13     22     08/01/2014
5     12     23     08/01/2014
5     13     23     08/01/2014
6     14     24     06/01/2014
7     15     25     09/01/2014
```

Comment: Your title mentions joins, which implies that there are multiple tables involved.  The names of your column headings also seem to imply that there might be 3 tables involved (a, b, and c).  Yet your description seems to imply that all of the fields come from one table: "Here's is my main table. where i have three column with there dates".  What exactly is your table structure?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `coalesce` funtcion

```
select a.id,bid,c.id, 
       coalesce(a.date,b.date,c.date) as date
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `coalesce()`:

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id, coalesce(a.date, b.date, c.date) as date
```